# How to get in Liferay calendar SyncEntryId of a single google recurring event?

Tags: java, liferay, google-calendar-api, liferay-7

I created a Calendar connector for google. My new functionality is delete a single occurrence of recurring events but it doesn't work. I'm not able to get the `SyncEntryId` of a single event.

```
syncEntry = SyncEntryLocalServiceUtil.fetchSyncEntry(
                getSyncGroupId(), mappedId);
```

This code create the id but when are reccurring events the pattern of id is like "`XXXXX_20190522`" and, in this case, sync entry is null. When it isn't a recurring events the id is like "`XXXXX`".

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the Google's Api ??

Comment: Yes, but the problem is the format of id. i tried to delete the "_20190522" but in this way delete all of recurring events after the syncronization with Liferay Calendar.